# is there any system or library that can intelligently assign text from array to specific fields in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

HEllo,

I have a situation here i have contents(NSStrings) in an array, is there any system or library that can assign the content of array to specific fields.

Please help if you have an idea about this.

Thnx in advance

(ok to elaborate)

say I have standard of a student then allocate it to standards text field corresponding to standard

If I have email then allocate it to email text field

I have some sentences or short text statements in a list, and I want the application itself to perform semantic parsing of this text and act on it by filling in the appropriate values.

Comment: Your question is way too vague. Please edit it to provide more information about what sort of “contents” you have.

Comment: if you can help well and good otherwise why waste time.........

Comment: The problem with your question is that is seems to ask about a task so basic that no one is sure if your actually asking about that very basic task of if your asking about something more sophisticated. Putting text into a text field is one of the first things you learn in iPhone tutorials. Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a for-loop.

Comment: @Ankit Your question is extremely vague and could be referring to any number of things.  It is you who is wasting the time of those trying to help, by not specifying exactly what you are attempting to do.

Comment: it may sound weared to you all.........

but dont you see i am querying about some Artificial intelligence about thing.........

atually I am asking about some AI syatem that assigns text of array intelligenty to some speific textfields......

and I know very well how to assign text to textfields lolll........

:-)

Comment: If I understand your comment, you have some sentences or short text statements in a list, and you want the application itself to perform semantic parsing of this text and act on it by filling in the appropriate values.  The question as worded leaves the impression that you as the programmer want to know how to fill in these fields, given a list of text items.

Comment: yes brad is absolutely correct........
now can you suggest some solution please........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand your question but I think this may be related to what you're looking for - [exZact data collection](http://www.iformbuilder.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Putting text into text field is a central operation on the iPhone. [See this tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/06_ImplementingController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH8-SW2) for a very simple app that changes the text in a text field. The source of the text to put in the field is largely unimportant. Just take the string out of the array, core-data, generator etc and stick it in the field.

If you have a more complex question, you should edit your question to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague:

- **contents in an array** -- array either
  has contents or it doesn't, that
  doesn't tell me anything. What kind
  of contents? NSArray containing
  NSStrings? Some other standard class?
  A class of your own?
- **fields** - are these a fixed group of fields, or does the number of fields needed depend on the NSArray's contents? do you want the fields to be editable, or do you just want to display data for reading?
- **standard of a student** - What is a "standard of a student"? Don't assume we know your project and its domain-specific language. Can you explain what you mean? Your name looks Indian, so if you're not a native speaker of English, maybe you looked up the wrong translation? Can you try other translations? Circumscribe what you mean? Your complete use of "standard" has me confused, I know no meaning of the word that fits the three occurrences in your sentence.

As to semantic parsing, I don't think the iPhone has finished classes for that (does the iPhone have NSScanner or a public API to data detectors? I think only the Mac had that).

However, once you've done the parsing of the string (e.g. using NSString methods like -hasPrefix:, -characterAtIndex:, -substringFromIndex etc.), you should be able to just assign each piece of text to your UITextField or whatever you have, like in any other app. If you don't know how to do that, read up on IBOutlets, the -setText: method etc.

If you do not have a fixed number of items, you'll either want to create the views manually (Just +alloc/-initWithFrame: the right UIView subclass and -addSubview:, and keep a pointer to the view in another array) or use a UITableView, which is suitable for all kinds of lists of things.